# Swapping MacPro 5,1 into 4,1 case

Tags: mac-pro

Does anyone know if it’s possible to swap a MacPro 5,1 into a 4,1 case. My 5,1s feet are damaged beyond repair. I know they both use the same sleds and iirc same trays of sorts. I believe they also share the same power supply size, etc. Motherboards different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread on [Apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7537539) that seems to suggest these are *physically* identical. I have no personal experience with these specific models but it *looks like* they may be identical.

Comment: Yes 4,1 and 5,1 are the same.

Comment: I just did it and it works completely. No problems.